# Is there a command in linux or maybe a tool which can show me the last files which has been added to the machine?

Tags: linux, performance

I'm investigating a growth in size of our disks in our Linux servers environment and a tool like that can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Good old `find` probably does what you need. Try for example

```
find /path/you/want -type f -mtime -1
```

That would return the files added/modified during the last 24 hours.

Comment: Though easily circumvented if the user knows this is the detection method.

Comment: Sure, if the intention is to scan the disk growth because of some malicious user, then things like auditd might be a better option. But on the other hand more difficult to setup.

Comment: Agreed; just thought I'd mention it so the user knows the potential pitfalls in advance.